# How can I make jQuery's draggable function expand the container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

If I have markup like this:

```
<!-- Other Content -->
<div id="container">
<div class="draggable">
</div>
<div class="draggable">
</div>
</div>
<!-- Other Content -->
```

How can I have the container div expand vertically (I only want #container to be capable of expanding downward) as I drag one of the draggables?  I've thought about using the drag callback, but there's gotta be a CSS way, right?

Comment: Simply clearing the content doesn't work? `#container{overflow:auto}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conclusion that I have come to is that this may not even be possible.  I went with an alternate method of using jQuery.resizable to do it manually instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with css, because div#container element didn't get any class triggered from draggables.

Best way is to do it with callback:

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
   start: function(event, ui) { $('#container').addClass('expand'); },
   stop: function(event, ui) { $('#container').removeClass('expand'); }
});
```

Comment: Okay, so what's in the expand class to make it expand?

Answer (score 0):

I have made some progress, but this is still not working the way I would like it to.
Here's how I now have it partially working (using the markup above):

```
 var dragCatch = function(event, ui) {
    var containerOffset = $('#container').offset().top;
    var containerBottom =  containerOffset + $('#container').height();
    var componentHeight = $(this).height();

    if (event.pageY > containerBottom - componentHeight - 2) {
        $('#container').height(event.pageY - containerOffset + componentHeight + 2);
        $(this).css('top', event.pageY - containerOffset);
    }
};

$(this).each(function() {
    $(this).draggable({
        grid: [117,1]
        ,snap: '.draggable'
        ,snapMode: 'outer'
        ,containment: '#container'
        ,drag: dragCatch
    })
});
```

This code will successfully resize the #container div, but will stop moving the .draggable div where #container used to end.  If I let go, then drag again, then the .draggable will again move to where #container ends, then will stop even if #container continues to expand in size.

Comment: if this is so that you can add resize bars to your container div then just use resizable() instead of draggable() . alternatively for your example remove the containment option if your growing your box you'll never reach the out each of the container anyway.

Comment: Yes, I could use a resize bar, but I'd prefer the page be capable of expanding in one action rather than two.  
Regarding the removal of the containment option, I realized my initial post was not all that clear in that I want the container div to expand in the vertical direction only. (I've now fixed it)